# How to bind function in vue js v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I asked a question which might be unclear to someone. So, I deleted that question and ask again with new approach. I have an API response something like this:

```
{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Item 1',
      items: [
        {
          slug: 'Phase 1',
          values: [
            {
              highValue: '12',
              lowValue: '8',
              color: 'red'
            },
            {
              highValue: '15',
              lowValue: '5',
              color: 'green'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          slug: 'Phase 2',
          values: [
            {
              highValue: '14',
              lowValue: '6',
              color: 'red'
            },
            {
              highValue: '15',
              lowValue: '5',
              color: 'green'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Item 2',
      items: [
        {
          slug: 'CBC',
          values: [
            {
              highValue: '10',
              lowValue: '7',
              color: 'green'
            },
            {
              highValue: '12',
              lowValue: '3',
              color: 'red'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have static block for `High Value`, `Low Value`, `Red` & `Green` in my HTML. So, for those static blocks, I need to pick appropriate value from the response. For example, for `High Value` & `Red` block, I need to pick `highValue` from the response when `color: 'red'`. So, I write four function for example:

```
redHigh (item) {
      const res = item.filter(obj => {
        return obj.color === 'red'
      })
      return res[0].highValue
    }
```

Now, I tried to bind the function in `v-model` like this way:

```
               <v-text-field
                  outlined
                  :v-model="redHigh(sub.values)"
                  placeholder="High"
                ></v-text-field>
```

But, that was not working. If I wrote `:value` instead of `:v-model`, that would work. But, in that case I don't get the changed value after clicking `save` button.

```
save (formIndex) {
      console.log(this.items[formIndex])
    }
```

[image]

How to solve that?

**[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/vYeKrOJ?editors=1010)**

Answer (score 2):

v-model is not for a function; it's for a Vue's data property.

However, I understand your app requirement.
You just need to create Vue computed properties, that can generate a dynamic array using a custom function bind input event from your text field

you can read `$emit` or `v-bind` documentation about it

---

I just read the API of v-text-field component here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props.

Just need to update it to use `value` prop and bind `change` event
[image: value prop]

[image: change event]

Which is would be like this

```
     <div v-for="(sub, index) in item.items" :key="sub.slug">

       <v-text-field
            outlined
            :value="redHigh(sub.values)"
            @change="updateSubValue(index, 'red', 'high')"
            placeholder="High"
            ></v-text-field>
```

```
updateSubValue(index, color, value) {
  // find current sub by index
  // find current value's key by color and value
  // update vue data
}
```

It might index first, been a long time I don't develop the Vue app

```
     <div v-for="(index, sub) in item.items" :key="sub.slug">
```

Or you can find the current sub by slug, no need to add index

Comment: But, we can't pass parameters to computed properties.

Comment: One way to do what you are trying is to use Array.map() on your data and create another property like redHigh. Then you can set v-model="item.redHigh" This would make redHigh property two way binding. If you need to save the data later you then process the array and convert the property to a value you need.

Comment: @user1896653 please check my updated answer

Comment: Can you fix your punctuation and capitalization, please?

Comment: done @RobertHarvey, am I right?

Comment: @SaiqulHaq, Thanks for your help. Can you please provide the solution with demo? I am struggling with writing the `updateSubValue` function. For example, for finding current value's key, I took `const valIndex = this.items[index].items[index].values.findIndex(item => item.color === color)` which gives me error for some block. And I don't understand what to do for updating vue data i.e `items[index].items[index].values[valIndex].value = ???` Also, the `slug` can be empty sometime. That's why, I should use index instead of slug i.e. `<div v-for="(sub, i) in item.items" :key="i">`